# Data Issue in Exporting data from SharePoint to SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010, ssis

I used SharePoint list adapter from CodePlex [SSIS Adapter](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SharePoint%20List%20Adapters&referringTitle=Documentation) to transfer my SharePoint list items to the SQL server 2008. The person/group picker field came with junk characters like

> 10;#Mark, Brown
>   4;#Samantha, Brown
>   100;#Tim, Collins

If the field has multiple people, it shows up like this:
7;#Sigmon, Russel;#18;#Colby, Fox;#23;#Rina, Meyer

I m envisioning two ways of solving this issue.

1) **Identify the source of the issue and correct the source:**
In this option, I know those #s are not random, but SharePoint assigned ID to each person and ;# are the separators.Can anyone suggest how to get rid of those #s and ;# in the package created using the above Codeplex link? is there any other way to get this resolved from SharePoint list itself? or in Package(SSIS)?

2) **Correct it in SQL:**
May be create a stored proc/function to strip out those characters and just have comma separated clean names? Can anyone point me how?

Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a SSIS package that is also applying the same SharePoint adapter to acquire information from multiple documents published in multiple SharePoint list locations.  I had a similar issue and applied the second approach you're considering by applying SQL.  The SharePoint records are first pulled into a temporary staging database table where I apply a few SQL UPDATE statements to clean the data, including the removal of the random # characters.  Afterwards, the records are then normalized into a final destination table.  In your case, you may need to apply SQL parsing of the value (using "#") and probably apply a cursor in order to place each name into individual records... if that's the eventual intent.

Hope this helps.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kosh, Thanks for your i/p. Initially I also thought the same but found more efficient solution- SQL CLR. If you could write a SQL CLR function and deploy that function to SQL Server, you could pass the desired column to the function that parses the data and gives u what u want in a simple SELECT query. I did it that way. I tried doing the way you said but felt frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way...

substring([Created by],charindex('#',[Created by])+1,len([Created by])-charindex('#',[Created by])) as [Created by]